# smoothness in Zariski's main theorem

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Suppose that $K$ is a field, $V$ and $W$ are $K$-varieties, and $f : V \to W$ is a quasi-finite morphism. One form of Zariski's main theorem is that $f$ factors as $V \to V' \to W$ where $V'$ is a $K$-variety, $V \to V'$ is an open immersion, and $V' \to W$ is finite.

Suppose further that $V$ is smooth. Can we take $V'$ to also be smooth? In my naive opinion this seems unlikely, but I would like to know for sure.

If this was true then I think I can produce an open immersion $V \to V'$ where $V'$ is a smooth proper  $K$-variety, so we run into issues with resolution of singularities. So I am willing to restrict to characteristic zero.

I would also be interested in a weaker statement. For example, could there be an open subvariety $V_0$ of $V$ such that the restriction of $f$ to $V_0$ factors as $V_0 \to V'_0 \to W$ where $V'_0$ is smooth, $V_0 \to V'_0$ is an open immersion, and $V'_0 \to W$ finite? Or could we at least take $V'$ to not be too "badly singular" in some sense?

Comment: This is not true. Take a finite covering $V_0\rightarrow W$, with $W$ smooth, $V_0$ normal but with a singular point $p$ (that is easy to construct), and $V=V_0\smallsetminus \{p\} $. Then  necessarily $V'=V_0$ which is not smooth.

Comment: alright, thanks!

Comment: @abx could you take $W$ to be $\mathbb{A}^m$ ? I think this is actually the only case that matters for what I am thinking about.

Comment: Yes — just take a double covering of $\mathbb{A}^m$ branched along a hypersurface with one singular point.